# How can i provide a consistent value to all the similar nodes using c#

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I am trying to insert some consistent value to all the similar nodes within.
sample xml is as follows:

```
 <DrWatson>
  <Bugs Name="Bug.add --> Nirvananaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>NeedsReview</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
    <Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea>Blank</subarea>
      <title>Bug.AddNote#1 : Dr.Watson Framework by Aman</title>
      <description>test</description>
      <appLanguages>English~~Bug</appLanguages>
      <platforms>Win XP All~~English~~Bug</platforms>
      <state>Open</state>
      <status>ToFix</status>
      <reason>Blank</reason>
      <failureType>Unspecified</failureType>
      <Frequency>Unknown</Frequency>
      <severity>0</severity>
      <priority>0</priority>
      <methodFound>Blank</methodFound>
      <foundInBuild>1</foundInBuild>
      <dev>bansal</dev>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <keyword>Blank</keyword>
      <duplicateId>Blank</duplicateId>
      <note></note>
    </Bug>
  </Bugs>
</DrWatson>
```

I would like to replace the values for `<foundinBuild>` tag.
Also, please note that i dont want to save the edits but wil use the edited xml in runtime for further in my code. Please suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
      var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Your XML Path");
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Bugs/Bug");                
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {                 
                    node["foundInBuild"].InnerText = "Your New Value";                   
            }
```

Comment: I tried but it's not replacing any node value as desired.Well it never comes in foreach loop.Please suggest.

Comment: @ Rajeev Kumar.. actually what i am observing is that "DocumentElement" text is not converting to blue whereas it's coming in the suboptions for doc.

Comment: In my side it runs actually good. Did you getting any exception ?

Comment: Does your xml has any root node ??

Comment: Well please refer to the exact xml where i am performing this operation. I guess there must be some change with respect to the exact xml i am using.I have updated the xml mentioned above.

Comment: @ Rajeev Kumar It's working. This is what exactly i was looking for.